# Bar chart remove space through aspect or axis limits constrains in or between subplots

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart, subplot

I am struggling to remove the empty space in or between subplots. I already read a lot of answers here, but I am not getting anywhere.
I want to make horizontal bar plots with several subplots:

My example is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [5]
y1 = [-10]

x2 = [30, 35]
y2 = [-15, -20]

x3 = [15, 5, 20]
y3 = [-10, -15, -30]

xlimits = [-30, 35]
ylimits = [-0.5, 2.5]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
ax1.barh(0, x1, height = 1)
ax1.barh(0, y1, height = 1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2)
ax2.barh([0, 1], x2, height = 1)
ax2.barh([0, 1], y2, height = 1)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)
ax3.barh([0, 1, 2], x3, height = 1)
ax3.barh([0, 1, 2], y3, height = 1)

for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.set_ylim(ylimits)
    ax.set_xlim(xlimits)

plt.show()
```

will result in:
[image: horizontal bar plot with gaps]

I used `ax.set_ylim(ylimits)` to have an equal height of all bars and `ax.set_xlim(xlimits)` to have "0" in one vertical line.

Now I would like to adjust the bbox to remove the empty space in the subplots (top and middle). But I have no idea how to achieve this. I also tried `ax.set_aspect()`. In this case I will receive empty space between the subplots.
I would like to do it with subplots to easily add description, swap stuff and so on.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could try adding this to your code:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response, but unfortunately, that doesn't change the plot.

Comment: it is strange, adding the line just before `plt.show()` removes the space in my plot